# Port 8899 in CLOSE_WAIT state and times out

Tags: rpc

I built a Solana RPC node on Ubuntu 22 but i am running into an error with making RPC/transaction requests to the node. I am able to connect through port 8899 but when i sent a request it seemd as if it goes through but does not return to complete the request. This is on mainnet which is synced up.
[image]

192.168.1.44 is the solana node.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.